# Some gmail message attachments return ValueError for some reason

Tags: python, gmail, imap

This is the code. (`cred.py` is a file containing my password and username)

```py
import os
from os.path import dirname,realpath
from imbox import Imbox 
import imaplib
import traceback
import datetime
from cred import *    # contains username and password
def main():
    p = dirname(realpath(__file__))
    host = "imap.gmail.com"
    download_folder = p+"\\"+username+"\\"+str(datetime.datetime.now())[:10]
    if not os.path.isdir(download_folder):
        os.makedirs(download_folder, exist_ok=True)
    mail = Imbox(host, username=username, password=password, ssl=True, ssl_context=None, starttls=False)
    messages = mail.messages(unread=True) # defaults to inbox

    for (uid, message) in messages:
       mail.mark_seen(uid) # optional, mark message as read
       for idx, attachment in enumerate(message.attachments):
            try:
                att_fn = attachment.get('filename')
                download_path = f"{download_folder}\\{att_fn}"
                print(download_path)
                with open(download_path, "wb") as fp:
                    fp.write(attachment.get('content').read())
            except:
               print(traceback.print_exc())

    mail.logout()
if input('Enter "test" to run now, else to run at 00:00 ') == 'test':
    main()

while True:
    if str(datetime.datetime.now())[11:-7] == "00:00:00":
        print('running')
        main()
```

For some reason some messages raise a `ValueError` and it looks like a bug in module. What do I do?

Comment: Please post the full error, including especially the line at which the `ValueError` takes place. To allow for this debugging, you may need to remove the outermost `try:` and `except ValueError: print('Error!')`, which may be eating your stack trace, depending on where the error is happening.

Comment: If you change the `except ValueError:` to `except ValueError as exc:` and then `print('Error!', exc)` you may get more information about the problem (and with that either fix things or possibly print out other variables as well to aid further debugging.

Comment: Edited it, no more error catching.

Comment: Try my lib, it is live https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools